# Clarification for sending credentials via HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, ssl, https

I have a website that is running on a server that integrates with the [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/). In order to authenticate requests, the site asks for the user credentials and sends those to JIRA to return back a session (see [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#auth/1/session-login)).

Obviously, I don't want these credentials floating around in plaintext. While this will be run on an internal network that does not face the outside, it is still important.

My question is (excuse the poor explanation): Do I need to acquire an SSL cert for MY server even if JIRA is using HTTPS. In this instance, JIRA has a valid SSL cert and is secured by HTTPS.

Rough overview of the 'flow':

```
User enters user/pass and submits HTML form (index.html on nodejs) -> 
    -> Request (HTTP POST) is sent to my server w/ creds (nodejs)
        -> My server sends a request to JIRA (HTTPS)
        <- JIRA responds with JSON
    <- Response is received by my server
<- My server sends data back to index.html
```

My thinking is I need HTTPS in this case due to this:

```
XX.XX.XX.XX <-/-> YY.YY.YY.YY <---> ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ

[XX] = client (index.html)
[YY] = server (nodejs)
[ZZ] = JIRA
```

In that 'diagram', the client sends the credentials to my server over HTTP, which is insecure. The server will then send the credentials to JIRA, which does have HTTPS enabled.

In this case, I'm assuming the credentials can be sniffed between X and Y, but not between Y and Z (I'm starting to confuse myself...)???

(P.S. I needed to put a server in the middle due to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) limitations. Everything is working fine other than the HTTPS issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right : the HTTP communication between the client X and your server Y is in clear text if there is no SSL configured on server Y. The credentials can be sniffed there, but can't be between Y and Z.

You can easily check with a tool like wireshark : https://www.wireshark.org/, if you run it on X or Y (or anything in between that might see the packets). Or the `tcpdump` command-line of you don't have a GUI (on Unix/Linux).

To secure this, you indeed need to switch to HTTPS on server Y, which implies to put a SSL certificate on it. You can test with a self-signed certificate (but the browsers will complain about it), and then put a valid certificate : as you seem to be in a corporate environment, you might have a corporate certificate authority trusted by your internal browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the credentials can be sniffed everywhere, encrypt everything.

Answer (score 1):

`Request (HTTP POST) is sent to my server w/ creds (nodejs)` is HTTP, not HTTPS, that is a security issue. Get a certificate and setup HTTPS with TLS 1.2.

Remember is is the user who suffers if the security is bad, put yourself in their place, do you expect the services you use on the Internet to have best practice security?